# Stop flickering when drawing multiple rectangles on picture box

Tags: c#

When drawing multiple rectangles in a picture box with the below code, it flickers.
What can I do about it?

```
private void drawRect(int sx, int sy, int ex, int ey, int w, int h)
{
    Brush cloud_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, Color.Black));
    //Top ok
    pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(cloud_brush, 0, 0, w, sy);
    //Bottom
    pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(cloud_brush, 0, ey, w, h);
    //Left ok
    pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(cloud_brush, 0, sy, sx, ey - sy);
    //Right
    pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(cloud_brush, ex, sy, w, ey - sy);
}
```

Comment: avoid using CreateGraphics(). use the paint event instead

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are using `CreateGraphics()` for every paint action but you only have to create it once. `CreateGraphics()` is slow so this will speed up your code a lot.

```
    private void drawRect(int sx, int sy, int ex, int ey, int w, int h)
    {
        using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
        using (Brush cloud_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, Color.Black)))
        {
            //Top ok
            g.FillRectangle(cloud_brush, 0, 0, w, sy);
            //Bottom
            g.FillRectangle(cloud_brush, 0, ey, w, h);
            //Left ok
            g.FillRectangle(cloud_brush, 0, sy, sx, ey - sy);
            //Right
            g.FillRectangle(cloud_brush, ex, sy, w, ey - sy);
        }
    }
```

The reason it flickers is the use of CreateGraphics.
I recommend you to use the paint event instead.

```
    private void drawRect(Graphics g, int sx, int sy, int ex, int ey, int w, int h)
    {
        using (Brush cloud_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, Color.Black)))
        {
            //Top ok
            g.FillRectangle(cloud_brush, 0, 0, w, sy);
            //Bottom
            g.FillRectangle(cloud_brush, 0, ey, w, h);
            //Left ok
            g.FillRectangle(cloud_brush, 0, sy, sx, ey - sy);
            //Right
            g.FillRectangle(cloud_brush, ex, sy, w, ey - sy);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        drawRect(e.Graphics,80, 190, 160, 140, 100, 130);
    }
```

Comment: `Graphic` as well as `Brush` implement `IDisposable` (to wrap HDC and HBrush handles correspondingly); please, wrap them into `using`

Comment: Dear i am using mouse events to draw these rectangles so what i should need to change there or how can i call this function there like i was calling my function as 
this.drawRect(this.startX, this.startY, this.endX, this.endY, width, height);

Comment: you can use Invalidate Method to repaint the control
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is all wrong. DoubleBuffered is __always on__ for a PictureBox. The only reson it flickers is the use of CreateGraphics. It should __never__ be used for persistent drawing!! All Painting should b done in the Paint event only. Doublebuffering is __not__ supported in Panels because they are __not__ really meant to be drawn on. One can still do it when using a Panel __subclass__, which turns DoubelBuffering on, though.

Comment: @Umair Shahid "if i share code would you correct it"
 update your question

Comment: I can have a look at it

Comment: @CodeJoy your email address pls

Comment: @TaW I know creating  the graphics object isn't slow but Creating a graphics object twice is unnecessary since paint already created the graphics object

Comment: Well that is better, but still: Using a `Graphics` object created with `control.CreateGraphics` is __not so much slow but wrong__ as anything drawn with it will not __persist__! Minimize/maximize and it is all gone! Therefor only draw with the `e.Graphics`object from the `Paint` event! - But of course creating the wrong object a lot of times is even worse ;-)